# BIM Metadata Extraction - Automation - Using AWS S3 bucket and Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are trying to implement an automation workflow as described below. Please let me know if it is possible to implement or not.
The workflow is going to be like this.

1. A user uploaded the Revit model to the AWS S3 bucket
   2)The Autodesk Forge model derivative API automatically fetches that model from the AWS S3 bucket
2. The model derivative API then extracts the metadata from the translated model and exports the metadata into an SQLite or JSON format and saves back that database file into the same AWS S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

This is feasible. you may combine a couple of services of AWS. I had similar practice long time ago. Probably it could be a reference

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/2-legged-workflow-model-translation-part-1

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/2-legged-workflow-model-translation-part-2

Note: some usage of AWS services may have changed. Forge side, the endpoints (using SDK) may be still working, but you also need to double test adjust if anything is tuned.